# How to prove that this representation is irreducible?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

> Consider the $3$ dimensional Lie algebra $L$ of differential operators
>   $$x=u\frac{\partial{ }}{\partial{v}},\text{ } y=v\frac{\partial{ }}{\partial{u}}, \text{ }h=u\frac{\partial{ }}{\partial{u}}-v\frac{\partial{ }}{\partial{v}}$$
>   on the space of smooth complex vaued functions in $u$ and $v$.
>
> (1) Prove that they satisfy satisfy
>   $$[xy]=h, \text{ }[hx]=2x, \text{ }[hy]=-2y$$
>
> (2) Prove using the killing form that $L$ is semisimple. Since $L$ is $3$ dimensional, this forces $L$ to be simple.
>
> (3) Prove that the set of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in $u$ and $v$ is a irreducible representation space of $L$.

I have proved the first two parts. But I am unable to prove the last part. Any ideas?

Comment: First, note that $h$ acts diagonalizably, then identify the eigenspaces of this. Then see what happens when you act by $x$ and $y$ on these eigenspaces.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The latter one is about the full space of polynomials, which does not yield an irreducible representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjoint operators for $L$ are given by
$$
ad (x)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0 &-2\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}, ad (y)=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&2\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}, ad(h)=\begin{pmatrix} 2&0&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
Hence the Killing form $\kappa(x,y)={\rm tr}(ad(x)ad(y))$ has matrix
$$
\kappa=\begin{pmatrix} 0&4&0\\4&0&0\\0&0&8\end{pmatrix},
$$
which clearly is non-degenerate for characteristic different from $2$.
Hence for characteristic zero $L$ is simple, and isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$.

Now the action by homogeneous polynomials is an irreducible $L$-module $V_n$. A proof is given in almost every text on Lie algebras. Here is an online-link:

[*The Story of $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{C})$ and its Representations
or Watch Charlotte Multiply $2 × 2$ Matrices with Her Left Hand*](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~charchan/RepresentationTheorysl2.pdf). The proof is given in Proposition $4$ on page $9$, and is prepared in section $5$.

Also related are the following questions:

[Formulas give irreducible representation, $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477269/formulas-give-irreducible-representation-sl2-mathbbc)

[Representation of $\text{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232436/representation-of-textsl2-mathbbc?rq=1)

Comment: The links mainly seem to discuss whether it really is a representation. Do you have a link where the irreducibility is explicitly shown? Possibly along the lines I gave in a comment (which I think will be the most elegant way without using knowledge of all irreducibles).